# Find variable-size range based on value of cell in same row

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to find the median of a range of cells that correspond to a condition in another column.

For the example pictured below that would be finding the median of the numbers in Column2 that have the same numbers in Column1. This is shown in Column3. The number of rows is dynamic, hence needing to associate this to Column 1.

Here is an example table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Column1        |     Column2      |      Column3     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         0.1      |        0.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         0.2      |        0.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         0.3      |        0.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         0.4      |        0.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |        1.5       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         2        |        1.5       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         1.1      |        1.1       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I've tried using `INDEX`, `MATCH` like this

```
=INDEX(MEDIAN(B:B), MATCH(A1,A:A,0))
```

but it's (obviously) incorrect. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet)

Use Filter to return the correct range to the Median function.

```
=median(filter($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A=A2))
```

[image]